# Mutual changes in two NSMutableArray objects

Tags: objective-c, object, nsmutablearray

Assume, your .h file looks like this:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *songs;
- (NSMutableArray *)popularSongs;
- (void)make20PercentDiscountToPopularSongs
```

Your .m file looks like this:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)popularSongs
{
    NSMutableArray *popularSongs = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (Song *song in self.songs) {

        if (song.isPopular) {

            [popularSongs addObject:song];
        }
    }

    return popularSongs;
}

- (void)make20PercentDiscountToPopularSongs
{
    for (Song *song in self.popularSongs) {

        song.price = song.price * 0.8;
    }
}
```

The code above adds a 20% discount to popular songs. I recognise that there is a more simplistic way of doing this. You could have the "make20PercentDiscountToPopularSongs" and "popularSongs" function in a single function but let's assume that the code is written the way it is written above.

In the example above, will the line:

```
song.price = song.price * 0.8;
```

Actually, make any changes to the object:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *songs;
```

Or not? Because, it seems as if the line will change the newly created popularSongs NSMutableArray rather than the songs NSMutableArray, am I right? This problem is bothering me for a lot of time now. **I would like to make changes just to the original songs array. To me popularSongs works as if you are storing the pointers to the songs in the songs array.**

Comment: Curious, why not have a "popular" flag or a "rank" field on the songs? Then you would only need one array that you can sort and filter.

Comment: Also, assuming the object for a popular song is the same object in both arrays, you only need to change the value once.

Comment: Brilliant but let's stick to the paradigm above.

Answer (score 3):

It changes neither array. It changes some of the objects in the `songs` array. And as the same objects are in the `popularSongs` array returned then they are 'changed' too.

This:

```
[popularSongs addObject:song];
```

Adds the pointer to the current song into the array. It doesn't create a new copy of the song.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. You're assigning a pointer of the song object to the popular song array. If you make a change to the popular song object it will change in the song array also.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a quick mutable array like this:

```
NSMutableArray *popularSongs = self.songs.mutableCopy;
```

Rather than iterating through *all* the songs to determine if they are popular, you could use a filter predicate at the time you create the array.

```
NSMutableArray *popularSongs = [[self.songs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
 [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isPopular = %@", @YES]] mutableCopy];
```

With this one-liner you can avoid your methods altogether ;-)- Not sure what you want, but if you want to alter the original songs, leave out the `mutableCopy` part.

Comment: Mutable copying the array doesn't copy the contents, it only copies the array (it's a shallow copy).